# show only one day of the week in radscheduler

Tags: c#, telerik, radscheduler

I am using radscheduler to show the agenda of driving instructors.
Next i find one or more instructors that have availability on a certain day of the week, for a couple of weeks. For instance : show the instructors that are available on friday between 10 and 12am for the next 5 weeks. This is done on a different page, no problems there.

After i found those instructors i would like to see them side by side in the scheduler, so i can start planning lessons for a customer. To do this i was thinking of the multi-day view, but only showing fridays.
However, telerik support told me this is not supported by radscheduler, the multi-day view only supports a selected number of consecutive days, you are not able to select the days to be shown.

So my next question is : who has a good idea how to do what i want ?
I am thinking in the direction of showing multiple instances of the radscheduler below eachother, each only showing 1 day for 1 or more instructors. Will this work technically and any ideas about the performance ?

Comment: better ask this question on telerik forum!

Comment: I already contacted telerik (have a valid support contract), but was hoping for some 'outside the box' thinking of my fellow stackoverflow telerik users :)